# Returning object of same subclass in __add__ operator

Tags: python, inheritance, operator-overloading, overloading

I am developing a simple type system for my own interpreter.
I am writing something like this:

```
class Base(object):
    def __init__(self, content):
        self.__content = content

    @property
    def content(self):
        return self.__content

    @content.setter
    def content(self, value):
        self.__content = value

class Number(Base):
    def __init__(self, content):
        super(Number, self).__init__(content)

    def __add__(self, other):
        return Number(self.content + other.content)

    ...and so on

class Float(Number):
    def __init__(self, content):
        super(Float, self).__init__(content)

class Integer(Number):
    def __init__(self, content):
        super(Integer, self).__init__(content)
```

My problem is that obviously if I do something like this:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    f1 = Float(3.5)
    f2 = Float(2.3)
    f3 = f1 + f2
    type(f3)
```

I have summed f1 and f2, which are Float type, but I have obtained f3, which is Number type, but I would like f3 to be a Float type. How could I define my add operator just one time in my Number superclass returning a type which is the same of f1 and f2? Have I to use isinstance? Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Thank you!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You could do something with [`__class__`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__class__#instance.__class__):

```
def __add__(self, other):
    return self.__class__(self.content + other.content)
```

As, @Eric points out, you may want to do something like

```
if self.__class__ == other.__class__:
    <use __class__>
else:
    <use Number>
```

to ensure predicable behaviour (or some other action if the classes don't match).

[`__radd__`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#object.__radd__) is also worth overriding here:

```
__radd__ = __add__
```

which will make `Number(1) + Float(1) == Float(1) + Number(1) == Float(2)`

Comment: You might want to think carefully about whether you want `self.__class__` or `other.__class__`

Comment: Oh, thank you. It works perfectly. I thought self.__class__ in the Number class would have been equal to 'Number'... I was wrong.

Comment: To expand further, I think you want `{(1, 0): self.__class__, (0, 1): other.__class__}.get((issubclass(self.__class__, other.__class__), issubclass(other.__class__, self.__class__)), Number)`. That would be less obtuse if I din't have to fit it in a comment.

Comment: Actually, scrap that. Just alias `__radd__`, and python will take care of things

Comment: @Eric, feel free to edit it into my answer since it will be clearer there.