# Initializing an object in a parent class with the type of the child

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, types, super

I wrote a parent class where I define a few functions (examples __mul__, __truediv__, etc.) that all of the child classes should have. These functions should keep the type of the child class after they have been executed.

Here some code to explain what I mean:

```
class Magnet():
    
    def __init__(self, length, strength):
        
        self.length = length
        self.strength = strength
        
        return
    
    def __mul__(self, other):

        if np.isscalar(other):
            return Magnet(self.length, self.strength * other)

        else:
            return NotImplemented
        
class Quadrupole(Magnet):
    
    def __init__(self, length, strength, name):
        
        super().__init__(length, strength)
        
        self.name = name
        
        return
```

Now if I do this:

```
Quad1 = Quadrupole(2, 10, 'Q1')
Quad2 = Quad1 * 2
```

Then Quad1 is of type '__main__.Quadrupole' and Quad2 of type '__main__.Magnet'.

I would like to know how to do this such that the type of the child is kept and it is not recast into a parent type. One solution would be to redefine these functions in the child classes and change

```
        if np.isscalar(other):
            return Magnet(self.length, self.strength * other)
```

to

```
        if np.isscalar(other):
            return Quadrupole(self.length, self.strength * other)
```

but the main reason to do inheritance was to not copy paste code. Maybe something like super() but downwards or maybe some placeholder for the class type...

I'm thankful for any help.

## Adopted solution

Using

```
return type(self)(self.length, self.strength * other)
```

does the charm. It raises an error because I forgot to add the 'name' argument in the Magnet.__init__() (my original code does, but messed up when simplifying for the example).

I also found the same question here: [Returning object of same subclass in __add__ operator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16750016)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Solution 1

You can get the type using `type(self)` and create a new object out of that.

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if np.isscalar(other):
        return type(self)(self.length, self.strength * other)
    raise NotImplemented
```

(Also raised the `NotImplemented` instead of returning it.)

Now using your code will result in:

```
    return type(self)(self.length, self.strength * other)
TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Which would require `Quadrupole` to have a default argument for `name`.

```
class Quadrupole(Magnet):
    def __init__(self, length, strength, name='unknown'):
        super().__init__(length, strength)
        self.name = name
```

And you code is happy, but you might not be happy. The reason is that you now lost information about the `name` of the `Quadrupole` class.

### Solution 2

You are returning a new instance of the class, sometimes this is not required and you can just mutate the old class. This would simplify your code to:

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if np.isscalar(other):
        self.strength *= other.strength
        return self
    raise NotImplemented
```

This would mutate your old instance.

### Solution 3

The main issue with solution 1 is that you lose information because you are creating a new class. Now a possible alternative would be to just copy that class. Unfortunately copying a class is not always that straightforward.

Based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48338847/how-to-copy-a-class-instance-in-python) SO question, probably using `deepcopy` would work in this case, but if you have a complex class structure you might have to implement `__copy__` to get what you want.

```
def __mul__(self, other):
    if np.isscalar(other):
        class_copy = deepcopy(self)
        class_copy.strength *= other
        return class_copy
    raise NotImplemented
```

Where optionally you can provide a `__copy__` method. For the provided code snippet this was not necessary, but in more complex cases it might be necessary.

```
def __copy__(self):
    return Quadrupole(self.length, self.strength, self.name)
```

Comment: I'm sorry I messed up the thing with the name by trying to make a simple case to show here. In my real case the parent Magnet also has a name. I will keep the question as is because you solve an additional possible problem. I like a lot the `return type(self)(self.length, self.strength * other)` and also found `self.__class__()`. I could not find a big difference between both for python 3.x.

Comment: About `NotImplemented`: I found here (<https://stackoverflow.com/questions/878943/>) that it is better to `return` instead of `raise`. At least as far as I understood.

Comment: @Felipe, I learned something new there, I usually always raise `NotImplementedError`. About the difference between `type` and `__class__`, I think [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-are-metaclasses-in-python/6581949#6581949) post might help a bit with it.

Comment: Thank you for the link. I guess it is probably to always use the almighty `type()` since \_\_class__ is easily overwritten.